# Is it possible to create a "delete" hotkey for left hand use?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

**Question**

Is is possible to create a hotkey in Ubuntu or in Eclipse for "delete" that is on the left side of the keyboard so that I can use my left hand for it? Or does such a hotkey already exist?

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> removes whole lines so it doesn't work
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> overwrites whatever I have on the clipboard so it doesn't work
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd> is not on the left hand side of the keyboard
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>backspace</kbd> is not on the left hand side of the keyboard

**Background**

As a programmer I often find myself needing to delete some word from multiple places in my code (say I just removed a parameter from a method and need to update all code that is calling it). I keep using the mouse to mark the words by doubleclicking them and then deleting them. The problem is that normally I have my left hand on the left part of my keyboard and moving it to the <kbd>delete</kbd> keyboard button and back costs precious time!

Being able to mark words with my right hand and deleting them with my left one quickly would speed up some tasks.

Sorry if this is a stupid question but it really bothers me...

Comment: Look in Preferences -> General -> Keys for delete.

Comment: Thank you! If you add this as answer I would accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `General` -> `Keys`. Search for `delete`, select `Delete`, press <kbd>Copy Command</kbd>, put something in `Binding:` (e.g. `Shift+A`), <kbd>Apply</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not addressed correctly and since Windows 10 keep changing the place of the configuration of the keyboard and I am going to tell how I did it.

Download Microsoft Power Toys [here](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/releases/) > Keyboard Manager > Remap a shortcut :
replace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> or whatever you would prefer.